# Caption under table

Tags: tables, captions

Is it in any way possible to make a caption right under my table? I've tried `\caption{table 1}`, but that does not work, nothing changes.

And how do I get the text aligned to the left in the column?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c || c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \thead{\makecell{Ønskede\\ egenskaber}} & \thead{Holdbarhed} & \thead{Pris} & \thead{\makecell{Billigt\\ og nemt}} & \thead{Miljøvenligt} & \thead{Udseende} &  \\ 
    \hline \hline
    \textbf{\makecell{Vægtning\\ (V) 1 - 5 \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & 4 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 2 & \textbf{\makecell{Sum\\ (P$\cdot$V)}} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{\makecell{Energibar\\ (P) 1 - 5\\ \\ P$\cdot$V \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & \makecell{3 \\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{4\\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{2\\ \\ \textbf{10}} & \makecell{3\\ \\ \textbf{9}} & \makecell{4\\ \\ \textbf{8}} & \makecell{\\ \\ \textbf{51}} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{\makecell{Fitnessapparat\\ med display\\ (P) 1 - 5\\ \\ P$\cdot$V \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & \makecell{\\ 5\\ \\ \textbf{20}} & \makecell{\\ 4 \\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{\\ 5 \\ \\ \textbf{25}} & \makecell{\\ 4\\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{\\ 2\\ \\ \textbf{4}} & \makecell{\\ \\ \\ \textbf{73}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{\makecell{Vindmølle\\ med solceller\\ (P) 1 - 5\\ \\ P$\cdot$V \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & \makecell{\\ 3\\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{\\ 1\\ \\ \textbf{3}} & \makecell{\\ 2\\ \\ \textbf{10}} & \makecell{\\ 5\\ \\ \textbf{15}} & \makecell{\\ 3\\ \\ \textbf{9}} & \makecell{\\ \\ \\ \textbf{49}} \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Tabel 1}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Please always post a _complete_ document. By default captions are not "moved" at all they go under or over the table depending whether you put the \caption before or after the tabular. But some document classes and packages redefine \caption to position according to a document property. So the answer depends on information you have not given as to your setup. your columns are centered as you use `c c...` use `l` fro any column thatyou want left aligned

Comment: Would you post a minimal working example? Unless you're using a package/class that manages caption positioning. Normally, if you call the `\caption` command after the tabular environment, the caption will be under the table.

Comment: What is the intended behaviour from `\fontsize{0}{.}`  It would generate a syntax error at the next font selection as `.` is not a legal length, but what do you want a font size of 0pt to do, it would make invisible text?

Comment: Typographical pointer: Normally captions for tables are placed above them and captions for figures are placed under them.

Comment: David and Bernad, none of those things work. Using "l" instead of "c" makes no difference and neither does the \caption whether if I place it above "\begin{tabular}" or below "end{tabular}". But I think it has something to do the "\makecell" command.

Comment: I think you forgot to use the `table` environment? :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this. Here `caption` package is used. You can adjust `skip=xx` to suit your need.

To have text aligned to the left, use `\makecell[l,r,b]{content}` for left, right or bottom alignment.

[image]

**Update:**

Code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm,papersize={15cm,15cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}   
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage{makecell,interfaces-makecell}
\usepackage[font=small,skip=0pt]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{| c || c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \thead{\makecell{Ønskede\\ egenskaber}} & \thead{Holdbarhed} & \thead{Pris} & \thead{\makecell[l]{Billigt\\ og nemt}} & \thead{Miljøvenligt} & \thead{Udseende} &  \\ 
    \hline \hline
    \textbf{\makecell[l]{Vægtning\\ (V) 1 - 5 \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & 4 & 3 & 5 & 3 & 2 & \textbf{\makecell{Sum\\ (P$\cdot$V)}} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{\makecell[l]{Energibar\\ (P) 1 - 5\\ \\ P$\cdot$V \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & \makecell{3 \\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{4\\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{2\\ \\ \textbf{10}} & \makecell{3\\ \\ \textbf{9}} & \makecell{4\\ \\ \textbf{8}} & \makecell{\\ \\ \textbf{51}} \\ 
    \hline
    \textbf{\makecell[l]{Fitnessapparat\\ med display\\ (P) 1 - 5\\ \\ P$\cdot$V \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & \makecell{\\ 5\\ \\ \textbf{20}} & \makecell{\\ 4 \\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{\\ 5 \\ \\ \textbf{25}} & \makecell{\\ 4\\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{\\ 2\\ \\ \textbf{4}} & \makecell{\\ \\ \\ \textbf{73}} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{\makecell[l]{Vindmølle\\ med solceller\\ (P) 1 - 5\\ \\ P$\cdot$V \\ \fontsize{0}{.}}} & \makecell{\\ 3\\ \\ \textbf{12}} & \makecell{\\ 1\\ \\ \textbf{3}} & \makecell{\\ 2\\ \\ \textbf{10}} & \makecell{\\ 5\\ \\ \textbf{15}} & \makecell{\\ 3\\ \\ \textbf{9}} & \makecell{\\ \\ \\ \textbf{49}} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Tabel 1}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use the `center` environment inside `table`; a simple `\centering` declaration is better, for it doesn't add extra vertical space.

Comment: Agreed and corrected accordingly, thanks for reminding.

Comment: You should probably also add the instructions `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` so that characters such as `ø` and `æ` will get typeset correctly.

Comment: @Mico, egreg -- Many thanks for the helping hands.

Comment: You are sure bent on ending that document!